# Density functions plotted with inaccuracy due to Findroot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

`f0` and `f1` are Gaussian densities and according to theory `gg0a` and `gg1a` are supposed to be density functions as welll. I am interested in finding `gg1a/gg0a`. The problem is about inaccuracies of `gg0a` for ca `y>2.5`. If I add  `MaxIterations ->1000` to FindRoot I get different results for `gg0a` for `y>2.5`.

I want to know the correct `gg0a` for `y>2.5`. According to theory it should be positive not negative as Mathematica gives me. What is the problem here?

```
{l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a} = {0.5031455894441628` , 0.5530384727475807` , 0.4419080848237867` , 0.44140972882917756` };
 \[Alpha]2a = 0.1;
 u = 0.5;
 f0[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y]
 f1[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]
 l[y_] := f1[y]/f0[y]
 lleq3a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1]^(\[Alpha]2a - 
  1) == ((m1 - u*llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1]^(u - 1) + 
    l1/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))/(m0 + (u - 1)*
     llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1]^u + l0/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))) (l0/l1)*
l[y]^(\[Alpha]2a - 1), {llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1], 1}]
 gg0a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] := ((m0 + (-1 + 
      u) (llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1] /. lleq3a[y, l0, l1, m0, m1])^
     u + l0/(1 - \[Alpha]2a)) ((1 - \[Alpha]2a)/
   l0))^(1/(\[Alpha]2a - 1))*f0[y]
 gg1a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] := ((m1 - 
   u (llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1] /. lleq3a[y, l0, l1, m0, m1])^(u - 
       1) + l1/(1 - \[Alpha]2a)) ((1 - \[Alpha]2a)/
   l1))^(1/(\[Alpha]2a - 1))*f1[y]
 LogPlot[Abs[gg1a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]]/Abs[gg0a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]], {y, -10, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", AspectRatio -> 0.7, PlotRange -> {All, {3*10^-9, 10^45}}]
```

[image]

```
 Plot[{gg0a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a], gg1a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Update 1:**

I used the NSolve instead of FindRoot as follows

```
 lleq3a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] := NSolve[z^(\[Alpha]2a - 
  1) == ((m1 - u*z^(u - 1) + 
    l1/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))/(m0 + (u - 1)*z^u + 
    l0/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))) (l0/l1)*l[y]^(\[Alpha]2a - 1), z]
```

My figure is now working for positive y axis completely but now it fails for the negative values which are less than -3. Note that blue and yellow curves are f0 and f1 densities in the figure below and the others are gg0a and gg1a.

[image]

Could one combine both methods or maybe use NSolve in a more clever way?

**Update 2:**

I used `WorkingPrecision -> 100` in NSolve and I got this [image]

Its really excellent now but I cannot verify that this result is now correct. Because when I use

```
 NIntegrate[Abs[gg0a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]], {y, -5, 5}]
```

I get no result (I need to get `1`). Instead I got a warning:

```
.... is not numerical at {y} = {-4.92043}
```

Comment: What is `llxxa` ?

Comment: @JimB it is just a variable.

Comment: Is it not a function not included in your code?

Comment: @JimB no. there is nothing missing in the code. just copy and paste the code and it will give you the figure in the question. maybe one could just put "x" instead of llxxa[...]

Comment: I think you've given far too much code which makes it difficult to find the problem.  It seems that the problem is with `lleq3a`.  If you run `lleq3a[2.5, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]`, you get a "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.".  Adding in `MaxIterations -> 5000` then gets you "Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point..." warning/error message.  Good luck.

Comment: @JimB yes exactly. thats the problem for which I am looking for a solution.

Comment: This question is  too long and lacks clarity. Moreover, instead of providing a bunch of code that is difficult to comprehend, it should explain what is the statistical problem you are trying to solve (something to do with the ratio of Normal random variables?), and not use numerical parameter values when symbolic exact solutions might exist and make the entire exercise redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Use exact constants and specify a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) in the [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html). [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) the plots.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

{l00a, l11a, m00a, 
   m11a} = {0.5031455894441628`, 0.5530384727475807`, 0.4419080848237867`, 
    0.44140972882917756`} // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

α2a = 1/10;
u = 1/2;
f0[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y]
f1[y_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]
l[y_] := f1[y]/f0[y]

lleq3a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, m1_?NumericQ] :=
  FindRoot[
  llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, 
     m1]^(α2a - 
      1) == ((m1 - u*llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1]^(u - 1) + 
        l1/(1 - α2a))/(m0 + (u - 1)*llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1]^u + 
        l0/(1 - α2a))) (l0/l1)*l[y]^(α2a - 1), {llxxa[y, l0, l1,
     m0, m1], 1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

gg0a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, 
  m1_?NumericQ] := ((m0 + (-1 + 
          u) (llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1] /. lleq3a[y, l0, l1, m0, m1])^u + 
       l0/(1 - α2a)) ((1 - α2a)/l0))^(1/(α2a - 1))*f0[y]

gg1a[y_?NumericQ, l0_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ, m0_?NumericQ, 
  m1_?NumericQ] := ((m1 - 
       u (llxxa[y, l0, l1, m0, m1] /. lleq3a[y, l0, l1, m0, m1])^(u - 1) + 
       l1/(1 - α2a)) ((1 - α2a)/l1))^(1/(α2a - 1))*f1[y]
```

Plots

```
LogPlot[Abs[gg1a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]]/
   Abs[gg0a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]], {y, -10, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  AspectRatio -> 0.7, PlotRange -> {All, {3*10^-9, 10^10}}] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@{gg0a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a], 
    gg1a[y, l00a, l11a, m00a, m11a]}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{gg0a, gg1a}, {.85, .7}]] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: I think the result is wrong. Just plot f0 and f1 densities together with those gg0a and gg1a. Another way to see that there is something wrong is to plot the same things from -4 t0 2 without using workingprecision->15. gg0a and gg1a are density functions which must have unit area so NIntegrate over all values should give 1.

Comment: I used NSolve and it worked now for positive y values! but it failed for y<-3.. I dont know if one could combine both methods or use NSolve in a better way. NSolve[z^(\[Alpha]2a - 1) == ((m1 - u*z^(u - 1) +  l1/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))/(m0 + (u - 1)*z^u + l0/(1 - \[Alpha]2a))) (l0/l1)*l[y]^(\[Alpha]2a - 1), z]